# How to PDF a Word document that has an embedded Excel document

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, pdf

I created a PDF policy manual compiling several Word documents with custom headers & footers.  Some documents now have attached excel exhibits.  NOTE: it isn't necessary to link the spreadsheet, just for someone to see it.  I was able to embed the excel worksheet in the Word document but the embedded spreadsheet will not print nor PDF, even though I can see it on my screen.  I also tried converting the Excel document into a JPEG and was able to insert that graphic into the Word document but had the same result when I JPG.  Thanking you in advance for your help.

Comment: "I also tried converting the Excel document into a JPEG and was able to insert that graphic into the Word document but had the same result when I JPG." - You mean to say a simple inserted JPG also failed to print or prevented the DOC from being saved as a PDF? Did you replace all the embedded Excel files with JPGs?

Comment: #JD, the meaningful execution should insert Excel file as ICON with Link, so that the  reviver may visualize it . But you may go this way when you are distributing it around Local Network or Sharable Drive. If  you Mail the file then receiver could not see Excel contents. Therefore better Copy & Paste either simply or with link the Excel Sheet into Word document and Save it as PDF.

Answer (score 1):

I too had this problem, but found the solution at last

1. for proper format you may convert the embedded objects (PDF's, Word,Excels) in policy as a link but after converting it to PDF it shows as image but format remains same means name which you want.
2. Upload all the files(password protected-UN-editable) which you want to link in policy(encrypted) to your google drive and give permissions to everyone who has this link.
3. open converted PDF (Policy Document or any) in Adobe Acrobat DC or Any Adobe PDF Editor then right-click on the Icon or document which you hyperlinked in the root policy document then click -> create link and select invisible rectangle -> then at left bottom click open web page and click ok then it popups url space then go to your google drive where you saved all your supporting documents for this policy then right-click on the particular document you wanted to link and get shareable link copy it and paste in the URL space in pdf editor and click ok and save the document :-) now your policy with embedded documents will work in pdf mode also. Enjoy bro... I just searched about same issue so i found yours too so am posting this now may be you already sorted out .. if not am happy that i solved yours tooo...

Answer (score 0):

Once your Word doc with linked Excel sheet is ready, use the 'export' function under the File menu, rather than 'save as'. Select 'Create PDF/XPS Document' and it will embed the spreadsheet into the PDF.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work with an embedded PDF in the Office 365 version of Word.